# Python: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable on a non empty query result

Tags: python, sqlite

I get `object is not subscriptable` on a non empty query result. When i print
`c.fetchone()` it prints the correct result but when i check the type it says `<class 'NoneType'>`

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("scraping.db")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Terminate (numar INT, arj INT )')
conn.commit()
c.execute('DELETE FROM Terminate')
conn.commit()
c.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Terminate ( numar, arj ) VALUES (1,0)')
conn.commit()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM Terminate") # ORDER BY numar DESC LIMIT 1")
print(c.fetchone(), type(c.fetchone()))

ins = c.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: There are no more rows available (your table clearly has only one row). You can store the first result if you intend to reuse that: `result = c.fetchone()`

Comment: if you want to play more with the same line, you have to keep a reference like `res = c.fetchone()` then `print(res, type(res))` will work as you expect

Comment: i still can not retrieve the first element of that `result = c.fetchone()`

Comment: `ins = result[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: you can only call `c.fetchone()` once

Comment: @PRMoureu thank you, i did not knew that, now i understand  that the first time i call it is in the print statement , so the second time i call it to assign it to a variable it retrieves nothing, you can give an answer and i will accept it, as you made me understand

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see @PRMoureu comment. She/he is completely right. It happens because you already have fetched both your values in print. You need re-execute SELECT or remove your print:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("scraping.db")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Terminate (numar INT, arj INT )')
conn.commit()
c.execute('DELETE FROM Terminate')
conn.commit()
c.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Terminate ( numar, arj ) VALUES (1,0)')
conn.commit()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM Terminate") # ORDER BY numar DESC LIMIT 1")


ins = c.fetchone()[0]
print ins, type(ins)
```

The output seems ok

```
1 <type 'int'>
```